# Check HTTP response header with partial recv() in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I am writing a web proxy that handles HTTP requests.

There are two cases:

1. When the `Content-Type` from the web server to the proxy is `text/html`, I want to concatenate all `recv()`s into a string.

```
std::string entire_response;
while(recv(...,buff,...,...)>0)
{
  entire_response += buff;
}
```

2. Otherwise, `send()` back to the client immediately after every `recv()`.

```
while(recv(...,buff,...,...)>0)
{
   send_back_all(buff,....);
}
```

What I was thinking:

```
bool flag = false;
std::string entire_response;
while(recv(...,buff,...,...)>0)
{
   if(flag||buff.contains("Content: text/html"));
   {
      entire_response += buff;
   }
   else
   {
      send_back_all(buff,....);
   }
}
```

The problem is that, how can I check the `Content-Type` is `text/html` when the first `recv()` may not contain enough information. For example, the first recv() cuts `Content-Type: text/html` like `Content-Text: text/ht`.

Comment: Read and buffer the whole message, then parse it and make decisions on how you want to process it.

Comment: The thing about reading the whole message into buffer is that, the ```recv()``` may contains binary data, say a JPG image, it cannot be appended by ```entire_response += buff``` as my prof says "If it is binary data, like an image, then you
should not be parsing it or appending it."

Comment: Your question already contains the answer: you do this by implementing the algorithm, as described. Implement the appropriate logic of repeatedly reading from the socket, tracking the read data, but parsing it as individual `\r\n`-terminated lines, until the blank line that ends HTTP headers is read. Every time a line is parsed check if it's `Content-Type:`, if so what it contains, then make the appropriate notes. There's really nothing else about this except to implement the appropriate logic, as described.

Comment: What is buff. Also += isn’t the only way to “append” to a string. Also, you’re not gonna get very far if you never parse binary data. I hope you just misunderstood your professor

Comment: You are trying to apply interpretation too soon. Some of the binary information is going to come out of the same `recv` call as some of the text. This is unavoidable, so don't immediately assume it is all text and throw it into a `string`. Instead look at the data. If it's still part of the text header, add it to the string. When you have the whole header, interpret it and deal with the left over data accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `while(recv(...) > 0)` loop, like you are trying to, to read HTTP messages (especially if HTTP keep-alives are used).  You need to *parse* a message's headers to know how the message's body is actually formatted on the connection, and thus can discover how the message is terminated.  You can't make decisions about the routing of the message before you have looked at its headers. An HTTP message can be terminated in one of several different manners, see [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) and [RFC Section 3.34](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3) for specific details, and also look at [past answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A65863+http+pseudo) of mine on this very topic.

You will have to receive and process the message's headers, THEN look for its `Content-Type` header, THEN do whatever you need with the headers you already have, then receive and process the message's body as needed until it is terminated.  THEN repeat for the next message.

So, something to the effect of the following (pseudo-code):

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> headers;
std::string header, entire_response;
char buff[1024];
int nbytes;

std::string response_line = readALine(...);
while ((header = readALine(...)) != "")
{
    headers.push_back(header);
}

// analyze headers to discover if message body is present and
// what its transfer format is in order to know how the message
// is terminated ...

std::function<void(const std::string &)> process_string;
std::function<void(char*, int)> process_bytes;

if (headers contains "Content-Type: text/html")
{
    process_string = [&entire_response](const std::string &str){
        entire_response += str;
    };
    process_bytes = [&entire_response](char* buf, int bufSize) {
        entire_response.append(buf, bufSize);
    );
}
else
{
    process_string = [](const std::string &str){
        send_all(str.c_str(), str.size());
    };
    process_bytes = [](char* buf, int bufSize) {
        send_all(buf, bufSize);
    };
}
else

process_string(response_line);
process_string("\r\n");

for (const std::string &header : headers) {
    process_string(header);
    process_string("\r\n");
}
process_string("\r\n");

while (message is not terminated)
{
    // decide how many bytes to read, based on the message's transfer format...

    nbytes = std::min(..., sizeof(buff));
    nbytes = recv_all(buff, nbytes);

    process_bytes(buff, nbytes);
}

if (!entire_response.empty())
{
    // use entire_response as needed...
}
```